# Focus not working on DoubleUpDown in latest version of wpf extended toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, wpf-extended-toolkit

I recently moved from version 2.0 to 2.6 of the extended wpf toolkit.
I have a `DoubleUpDown` in my code that I focus programmatically using the `Focus()` method. This worked in the old version but no longer works with the new one.
A simple test:

```
this.myDoubleUpDown.Focus();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.myDoubleUpDown.IsFocused);
```

This would output 'true' with the old version but 'false' with the latest.
Any idea how to fix this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

We recently noticed your post and did some tests. There is indeed a problem where DoubleUpDown doesn't take the focus.

After verification, it seems IsFocused() always returns false, in v2.0, v2.6 or v3.0.

However, for IsKeyboardFocuWithin(), it returned true up until v2.3, but false in v2.4 and later. We have fixed this issue (included in v3.1).